# How to patch data to material autocomplete when editing

Tags: angular, angular-material

i have an edit form that has a material autocomplete field. i cannot set the already selected value to the autocomplete when i need to edit

i tried the materialdesing but had no luck

i expect the drop autocomplete dropdown to be patched whent he data is recieved form the server, but i cant find a way to do it, please help

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
<input type="text" placeholder="Select a seller" aria-label="Number" 
matInput [formControl]="seller"
[matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="seller"/>
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" >
<mat-option *ngFor="let nameOfSeller of filteredOptions | async" 
[value]="nameOfSeller" >
                    {{ nameOfSeller.name }}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
                <mat-error *ngIf="seller.invalid && seller.touched">Required</mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```